# url with # as footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls

It seems that the symbol `#` on the `\url` inside `\footnote` is producing an error when pdf is compiled. This is reproduced by the **MWE** below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[numbers, super]{natbib}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula = chemformula ,
  modules = all
}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
 \footnote{\url{https://chemicalize.com/#/calculation}} 
\end{document}
```

**output:**

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again>
/
l.20 ...rl{https://chemicalize.com/#/calculation}}
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again>
```

I search similar posts about `#` but couldn't find anything. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the url before the footnote with `\urldef`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\urldef\urlchem\url{https://chemicalize.com/#/calculation}

\footnote{\urlchem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, but if you include `mhchem` in preamble, this doesn't work.  it seems, that `mhchem` is not compatible with `url`.  tested with recent `miktex`.

Comment: @Zarko: Works fine for me even with mhchem. (At least I get not error). Can you show your log-file?

Comment: log file: `! LaTeX  error: "kernel/property-unknown"
! The key property '.value_required:' is unknown.
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>.`

Comment: @Zarko Sounds like an outdated expl3. Did you run updates as user **and** as admin? (Edit: no, `.value_required:n` is the new code, `.value_required:` is old, so some package is probably outdated).

Comment: i use my pc as administrator. so far i didn't need to upgrade my miktex as user, it was sufficient as administrator. i should have recent expl3.

Comment: hm, i found problems with expl packages: somewhere i had installed  obsolete `\l3regex`. i will contact you in chat room.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with Overleaf and an easy workaround was escaping the "#" with "\".

See example:

```
\footnote{Some constrains apply, see \url{https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide\#constraints}}.
```