# \url with # and & inside \footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls, hyperlink

I have trouble with `\url` and `\footnote`

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

my text \footnote{\url{https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C69727&Type=HCOMBS#HCOMBS}}

\end{document}
```

this is the error message:

**! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.H ...gi/cbook.cgi?ID=C69727&Type=HCOMBS#HCOMBS}}**

Without the `&Type=HCOMBS#HCOMBS` link portion the code works fine, so I guess the problem lies in `&` character. Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Change `&` to `\&` maybe it'll work.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394807/32995

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an url with special chars you should define it (and the main problem is the `#` here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urldef\myurl\url{https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C69727&Type=HCOMBS#HCOMBS}
\begin{document}

my text \footnote{\myurl}

\end{document}
```