# Hyperlink with # in it

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, urls

I'm trying to insert a link which contains #, but i'm getting an error due to it. I've used \url and \href, but it does not work.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\section{Introduction}

En la tabla aparecen los tiempos de llegada que hemos marcado en 
cada uno de los sismogramas de las $46$ estaciones sísmicas. Es el 
tiempo en segundos que ha transcurrido desde el 
tiempo\footnote{\href{https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels?tab=overview}{https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp\#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels?tab=overview}} 
de referencia, las 21:00:00 TU.
```

It prints the direction, but it does not link to the one I want...

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394807/82917

Comment: use `\href{\url{...}}{...}`

Comment: Why not just use `\url{…}`?

Answer (score 1):

What's special about your setup is that the URL string occurs in a footnote. To display URLs in footnotes successfully, one needs to create "defined URLs" via `\urldef`. See section 2, "Defining a defined-url" of the user guide of the `url` package for more information on defined URLs.

Observe that I've replaced the two-argument `\href` directive in the OP's example with a single-argument `\url` directive. This is permissible since the two arguments of `\href` are the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks in URLs at arbitrary locations
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% Create a "defined URL", for use in the argument of a footnote:
\urldef\copernicus\url{https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels?tab=overview}

\setlength\textheight{3.5cm} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

En la tabla aparecen los tiempos de llegada que hemos marcado en 
cada uno de los sismogramas de las $46$ estaciones sísmicas. Es el 
tiempo en segundos que ha transcurrido desde el 
tiempo\footnote{\copernicus} de referencia, las 21:00:00 TU.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the special treatment of URLs in footnotes. I've just been using `\href` with no apparent problems. Is this issue unique to URLs with the `#` character?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL - I don't think the issue is unique to URLs that contain the `#` character. It can also arises with other, but not all, TeX-special characters. I say "not all" because not all TeX-special characters are legal in URL strings. For instance, I don't think I've ever seen curly braces or a backslash character in a URL string.