# URL not working because of #

Tags: urls, revision-control, href

I cannot seem to create a hyperlink to a specific line of a file on GitHub with the `\url` or `\href` commands. The following returns a 404 page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \url{https://github.com/SeSodesa/zeffiro_interface/blob/49fb5f652134e869c93809f05fbd70f0a730bbc4/m/forward_scripts/brain/lead_field_eeg_fem.m#L167}
\end{document}
```

I've traced this down to the fact that both `\url` and `\href` seem to replace the line number symbol `#` with its URL encoded counterpart `%23`, but GitHub does not understand this in the context where it happens. When I replace the `%23` with a `#` in the generated link, the URL works again.

My question then is, how do I fix this? The link is rather ugly and ends up flowing over page boundaries, so I would like to replace it with a short description via `\href` but still have a functioning link.

---

**Edit:** I think the problem might be the fact that the link is inside of a footnote. The code

```
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \footnote{\url{https://github.com/SeSodesa/zeffiro_interface/blob/49fb5f652134e869c93809f05fbd70f0a730bbc4/m/forward_scripts/brain/lead_field_eeg_fem.m#L167}}
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again>
```

When the number sign `#` is escaped, there is no error, but the link produced by `\url` does not function: https://github.com/SeSodesa/zeffiro_interface/blob/49fb5f652134e869c93809f05fbd70f0a730bbc4/m/forward_scripts/brain/lead_field_eeg_fem.m%23L167.

[image: A 404 page generated by the command \url.]

**Edit 2:** Looks like the link actually works in Adobe Acrobat... I was using Skim to read the document.

Comment: Works fine for me … PDF compiles and links correctly. If # actually works as an anchor, it must not be written as %23. Since it's working for me, perhaps your PDF reader does it?

Comment: I would probably use `xurl` for a better linebreaking. But it also works for me using TL22 and Evince as the PDF viewer. With and without `hyperref`

Comment: Looks like footnotes might have something to do with the issue. I've edited the post with more details.

Comment: you are on mac aren't you? It is a bug in some of their viewers and hyperref can do nothing about it. See https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/110

Comment: He actually uses Skim (see comment below) …

Comment: The safest way to use URLs in footnotes is via `\urldef`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394807/35864. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12855/35864

Comment: Special case of [hyperref - \href: broken links due to URL-encoding hash sign (# => %23) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555559/href-broken-links-due-to-url-encoding-hash-sign-23)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/url/url.pdf), *the `\url` argument cannot contain any `%`, `#`, or `^^`, or end with `\` if used in the argument to another command.*

That said, this actually worked for me (Sumatra PDF Reader):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xurl,hyperref}

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{\url{https://github.com/SeSodesa/zeffiro_interface/blob/49fb5f652134e869c93809f05fbd70f0a730bbc4/m/forward_scripts/brain/lead_field_eeg_fem.m\#L167}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It occurred to me to try another reader instead of Skim, and it turns out that Adobe Acrobat generates a functioning link, when I escape the `#` with a backslash. I guess I need to file a bug report to Skim developers.